# Looking for a free program where I can move a selection in multiple layers at the same time

Tags: layers, software-recommendation, selections

[image]
[image]

Is there a free software that can do this? So far I have looked at paint.net and GIMP, both of which unfortunately do not support this feature. All help is appreciated!

Comment: Sounds like an xy question

Answer (score 1):

One possibility is to use vector software. Inkscape is free and Open Source.

In the example below I have a bunch of blue squares on one layer, and a bunch of pink squares on a layer above. You can see me toggle the layers in the example

Use the Select and Transform Objects tool <kbd>F1</kbd> to make a selection around the squares you want to move, and it will also select the hidden squares in the layer below.  Holding down <kbd>Shift</kbd> adds to the selection when using this tool.

Then you can move all those selected as once, the pink and blue squares moving as one, even though they are on different layers.

Example

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I will check it out.

Comment: @EspenSales - if this is related to your other question, note that you can also import raster images into Inkscape.